# trying to arrange items in tableview cell- and they keep jumping

Tags: ios, tableview

I am trying to create a custom tableview cell

however, all my content inside keeps jumping around
This is how i put the objects in my view

[image]

and this is how the view renders during runtime

[image]

Why are my labels keep jumping ?

Comment: There aren't enough details here to answer your question.  Where do you modify the contents of the cell?  Can you show the code from that method?  If you're using autolayout, what constraints do you have set up?  What attempts did you make to resolve the issue, and what were the results?

Comment: there was absolutely no code supporting this - only layout issues, as idan moshe stated, i should have removed the checkmark from the storyboard that says "autolayout"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using auto layout tend to move the objects.
Disable it if you don't really use it and it won't jump.